# print array item of struct using pointer in c

Tags: pointers, struct

I am trying to print the value of an array using a pointer to that array's struct but I always get a segmenation fault.

thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
}POINTS;


int main() {

    POINTS *pointsmain;

    pointsmain->x = 10;
    printf("%d",pointsmain->x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the Segmentation Fault because your pointsmain pointer points to nothing. You just declare a variable of type pointer to POINTS. You must allocate memory on the heap for that. This is done by

```
    POINTS *pointsmain = (POINTS*)malloc(sizeof(POINTS));
```